# JavaScript/JQuery conditionally hide rows in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery, and would like to hide rows in a table depending on the value of one of its cells.

I have the following table:

```
<tr class="tr-class">
  <td class="status">
    <span class="status_submitted">submitted</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr-class">
  <td class="status">
    <span class="status_approved">approved</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I also have the following functions, where I can hide/show the `<tr>`.

```
function showSubmitted() {
     $(".tr-class").show();
}
function hideSubmitted() {
     $(".tr-class").hide();
}
```

But this hides/shows all the rows.

**Question**

How do I conditionally hide/show the rows?

For example, `function hideSubmitted()` should just hide the rows where the status cell is `submitted`.

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/31c90zbv/1/

Comment: You are using class = tr-class which overlooks all other id's .
You need to use something more paticuar for every particular row.

Comment: @Richard > $(".status_submitted").parent().parent().hide(); should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From your question:** For example, function hideSubmitted() should just hide the rows where the status cell is submitted.

For this you can change your code like it

```
  function hideSubmitted() {
    $('.status_submitted').closest(".tr-class").hide();
  }
```

this will find the closest tr-class to submitted one and hide that one only.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for text search and the answer is Jquery **contains**:

```
function showSubmitted() {
   $(".tr-class:contains(submitted)").show();
}
function hideSubmitted() {
   $(".tr-class:contains(submitted)").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using plain javascript , you could do some thing like :

```
function toggle_by_class(cls, on) {
    var lst = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
    for(var i = 0; i < lst.length; ++i) {
        lst[i].style.display = on ? '' : 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
function showSubmitted() {
    $(".tr-class").each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.status_submitted').length > 0) $(this).show();
    });
}

function hideSubmitted() {
    $(".tr-class").each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.status_submitted').length > 0) $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

And if you want to reduc your code you can do:

```
function showTr(type) {
    $(".tr-class").each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.status_'+type).length > 0) $(this).show();
    });
}

function hideTr(type) {
    $(".tr-class").each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.status_'+type).length > 0) $(this).hide();
    });
}

showTr('approved');
showTr('submitted');
```